# Installing Ubuntu from a partition on internal drive

Tags: system-installation, boot-partition

I am about to install Ubuntu on my new laptop, but I don't have access to a USB drive of any sort and it doesn't have an optical drive. Would it be possible to boot into the Ubuntu installer if I save it to a new partition on my hard drive and boot from there via the BIOS?

In case you need it, [here's a link to my profile](https://askubuntu.com/users/387134/its-willem?tab=profile), which lists my system specifications.

Thanks in advance for any assistance you may be able to provide. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is. You need to treat the partition as if it is a USB drive, so it may be hard to find a program that'll burn the ISO to it. It should work fine if you extract the installer ISO and copy the files to the partition. Make the partition NTFS or FAT32. If you have EFI, then use the BIOS EFI boot menu to select the partition as the boot source. If you can, disable Secure Boot in the BIOS.

I have done this before, and I think it was with Ubuntu, but I also had a third party bootloader, since I was also doing Hackintosh at the time. I don't remember whether or not I tried the built in selector to boot from the partition installer I made. Can't hurt to try though.

Sorry if this answer is a little erratic, as I'm a little tired **:P**
Just comment if you need clarification.

Comment: No clarification needed, this answered my question most adequately! Thank you :)

Comment: @It'sWillem (sell-out time :p) If it helped, would you mind accepting it? Thanks.

Comment: Turns out PenDriveLinux's USB Linux installer will work just fine for that; you must simply check "show all drives" and select your partition.

Comment: @It'sWillem Well, great!

Comment: That being the one listed in the Ubuntu Documentation as the ideal way to create a bootable drive for Ubuntu

Comment: Sadly, the installer will force you to go with "something else" during installation if you do it this way.

Comment: @It'sWillem well it's not like it's a supported method :p